# Checking out from Git make change detection not working

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am having a strange issue with Git and Idea

When i edit a file, the fiile name goes blue (as it does when you edit a vcs-controlled file)
But when i leave some time it goes back in white (non-edited vcs-controlled file) or/and when i click on commit it says "no changes detected"

When i click on invalidate cache and restart, all edited files goes blue again. But when i click on commit, it does an vcs refresh, says "no changes detected" and all files become white.

When i want to commit from a command line, no issues...

Commiting from idea worked before (you checked out from a git, created a new project reusing iml files, edited, commited pushed easy) but now it's the second computer i check out and it doesnt work...

Do you think i am doing something wrong? Or it's a bug?

Edit : It does only this on ONE project.
Other gitted projetcs commits fine.

Cheers

Comment: Did you verify that there were really changes on a given file by doing `git status` from the Git Bash?

Comment: Yep, git status give changes.